# Django admin read only fields with list_display and list_editable

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make only blank fields editable with list_display and list_editable options, I guess there are no way to do it from the "box"... but there must be methods like get_list_editable_field or way to create it and override builtin... does anyone know a way to do it?
[image]

Now I have just standard options, so I want only 'energy_quantity' be editable when is blank/None

```
class UserDataPeriodicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = (
    'prim_address',
    'sec_address',
    'energy_quantity',
    'heat_power',
    'time_date',
    'apartment',
)
list_editable = ('energy_quantity',)
readonly_fields = (
    'prim_address',
    'sec_address',
    'energy_quantity',
    'heat_power',
    'flow_rate',
    'flow_t',
    'return_t',
    'time_date',
    'ver',
    'status_code',
    'apartment',
    'weather',
)
list_display_links = None
list_filter = (
    ('time_date', DateRangeFilter),
)
```

Comment: `I want only 'energy_quantity' be editable when is blank/None`... when *what* is Blank/None?

Comment: `list_editable` generates a formset and there is no "built-in" way to modify individual forms in the changelist formset. You may be able to do something by overriding `get_changelist_form` and returning a form with dynamic fields

Answer (score 0):

I returned to this question... figured out that there are some options to do this... to change visual style and other...
To prevent changing data it is bad idea to use

> form.fields['energy_quantity'].disabled = True

because there will be mess with forms in request. So You can copy whole

> def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None)

to admin.Model and slightly correct if statement where it's saving data to db

> if request.method == 'POST' and cl.list_editable and '_save' in
> request.POST

```
class MyAdminFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        if self.get_queryset()[i].field_editable:
            form = super()._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
            form.fields['energy_quantity'].widget.attrs['style'] = "color: #79aec8; border: 2px solid #79aec8"
            return form
        else:
            form = super()._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
            form.fields['energy_quantity'].widget.attrs['style'] = "color:  #b7b7b7 ; border: 1px solid #b7b7b7 "
            return form


    class UserDataPeriodicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = (
            'prim_address',
            'sec_address',
            'energy_quantity',
            'heat_power',
            'time_date',
            'apartment',
        )
        list_editable = ('energy_quantity',)
        readonly_fields = (
            'prim_address',
            'sec_address',
            'energy_quantity',
            'heat_power',
            'flow_rate',
            'flow_t',
            'return_t',
            'time_date',
            'ver',
            'status_code',
            'apartment',
            'weather',
        )
        list_display_links = None
        list_filter = (
            ('time_date', DateRangeFilter),
        )

        def get_changelist_formset(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formset'] = MyAdminFormSet
        return super().get_changelist_formset(request, **kwargs)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
   ...
        if request.method == 'POST' and cl.list_editable and '_save' in request.POST:
            if not self.has_change_permission(request):
                raise PermissionDenied
            FormSet = self.get_changelist_formset(request)
            modified_objects = self._get_list_editable_queryset(request, FormSet.get_default_prefix())
            formset = cl.formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=modified_objects)
            if formset.is_valid():
                changecount = 0
                for form in formset.forms:
                    if form.has_changed():
                        obj = self.save_form(request, form, change=True)
                        if obj.field_editable:
                            self.save_model(request, obj, form, change=True)
                            self.save_related(request, form, formsets=[], change=True)
                            change_msg = self.construct_change_message(request, form, None)
                            self.log_change(request, obj, change_msg)
                            changecount += 1
    ...
        return TemplateResponse(request, self.change_list_template or [
            'admin/%s/%s/change_list.html' % (app_label, opts.model_name),
            'admin/%s/change_list.html' % app_label,
            'admin/change_list.html'
        ], context)
```

Additionally there are other salvations, for example to check saving data in model.Model

```
class UserDataPeriodic(models.Model):
energy_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Спожито тепла, кВт*год')
field_editable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

__original_energy_quantity = None

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__original_energy_quantity = self.energy_quantity

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.energy_quantity != self.__original_energy_quantity and not self.field_editable:
        return
    else:
        return super().save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

I guess there are other options to play with rendered data in

> def changelist_view

[image]